# PHP - Sum in bidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

i've a bidimensional array like:

```
fruits [
    [apple, 10],
    [orange, 30],
    [banana, 7]
]
```

In a loop i want to update quantity depending on fruit type.
Ex: if i've 4 more bananas and 20 strawberry new array will be like:

```
fruits [
    [apple, 10],
    [orange, 30],
    [banana, 11],
    [strawberry, 20]
]
```

How could i do this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: where is your code you tried?

Comment: i've try to use temp arrays (fruit,quantity) pushing them in main array after checking with array_search function, but with no success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this: (it works for your array but there is a better solution below)

```
$old = [
    ["apple", 10],
    ["orange", 30],
    ["banana", 7]
];

$new = [
    ["banana", 4],
    ["strawberry", 20],
];

function sumArrays($old, $new)
{
    foreach($new as $n) {
        $fruit = $n[0];
        $found = false;
        foreach($old as &$o) {
            if($o[0] == $fruit) {
                $o[1] += $n[1];
                $found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!$found) {
            $o[] = $n;
        }
    }
    return $old;
}

var_dump(sumArrays($old, $new));
```

but it is not effective. it would be much better if the fruit name would be the key of the array:

```
$arr = [
    "apple" => 10,
    "orange" => 30,
    "banana" => 7
];
```

This way the sum function could be

```
function sumArrays($old, $new)
{
    foreach($new as $fruit => $value) {
        if(empty($old[$fruit])) {
            $old[$fruit] = $value;
        } else {
            $old[$fruit] += $value;
        }
    }
    return $old;
}
```

which is a cleaner code, and it's more effective